# Using Python 3.8 to access Google Drive, getting 404 on Authorization page

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Using Python 3.8 to access Google Drive, getting 404 on Authorization page

In my console: both "Authorized Javascript Origins" and "Authorized redirect URLS" are set to http://localhost:8080

Goal: have a python program read my files from my Google Drive
I must be missing something simple here, this should not be so difficult.
Thank you in advance for taking the time to look at this.

Accomplished:

- python 3.8 on Mac Book Pro
- set up a Google Developer Account, downloaded my JSON file
  This JSON file can then be used by Google Drive components and metadata wizard
  to access Google Drive via the OAuth method Service Account.
- successfully installed pydrive    python3 -m pip install pydrive

  ```
      Package                  Version
      ------------------------ ---------
      google-api-core          1.26.1
      google-api-python-client 2.0.2
      google-auth              1.27.1
      google-auth-httplib2     0.1.0
      google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.3
      googleapis-common-protos 1.53.0
      httplib2                 0.19.0
      idna                     2.10
      oauth2client             4.1.3
      oauthlib                 3.1.0
      packaging                20.9
      pip                      21.0.1
      PyDrive                  1.3.1
         :::                    :::
  ```
- downloaded JSON file from Google Console for my project

My code:

```
2  from httplib2 import Http
3  from oauth2client import file, client, tools 
4  
5  import logging
6  logging.basicConfig(filename='debug.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
7  SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
8  CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret.json'
9  store = file.Storage('storage.json')
10  credz = store.get()
11  if not credz or credz.invalid:
12      flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
13      credz = tools.run_flow(flow, store) 
14  
15  SERVICE = build('drive', 'v3', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))       # from Ref(A):
16  files = SERVICE.files().list().execute().get('items',[])
17  
18  for f in files:
19      print(f" {f['title']}  {f['mimeType']}")
```

```
debug.log is empty
```

Executing python <my_pgrm.py>

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id= .... 

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver

... pgrm is stuck waiting for a response
 

in the Chrome browser ...  Google login splash page comes up with 404 
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. 
To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/...

In my console: 
both "Authorized Javascript Origins" and "Authorized redirect URLS" are both set to http://localhost:8080
```

Some of my Research:
How to Access Google Drive using service Account JSON file
https://help.talend.com/r/E3i03eb7IpvsigwC58fxQg/ol2OwTHmFbDiMjQl3ES5QA

```
How to manage files in Google Drive with Python  June Tao Ching   2019
Ref:  https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-manage-files-in-google-drive-with-python-d26471d91ecd
      https://github.com/chingjunetao/medium-article/tree/master/google-drive-with-python


https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python

https://cloud.google.com/python
      Link to Python on Google Cloud
      Come learn about Python on Google Cloud by completing codelabs covering a
      wide range of topics such as compute, data, and machine learning.
       View Tutorial (link)  404 

https://advancedweb.hu/using-google-auth-in-javascript/
```

---

Comment: This is the important information from the error: "The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. 
To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/..."

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is quite confusing

1. Why are you setting  Javascript Origins with Python?
2. Why are you using a web browser credentials with python.
3. That [research](https://help.talend.com/r/E3i03eb7IpvsigwC58fxQg/ol2OwTHmFbDiMjQl3ES5QA) you have done shows using a Service account.

Basically you have now covered all three authorization types. I really think you should pick which type of authorization you need first then find the code that suits it.  Your mixing things.

## solution for your error redirect_uri_mismatch

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
> To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/...

The redirect URI must exactly match the URI that your request is coming from

`http://localhost:8080`  is not the same as `http://localhost:8080/` you are missing the trailing slash.

Not sure what makes you think you cant add a trailing slash. I just did.

[image]

Why are you even adding the **Authorized JavaScript origins** when your using python?  On that note why are you even creating web browser credentials I would have thought you would be using installed credentials.

## [Web browser credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python)

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

# Use the client_secret.json file to identify the application requesting
# authorization. The client ID (from that file) and access scopes are required.
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'])

# Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
# the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required. The value must exactly
# match one of the authorized redirect URIs for the OAuth 2.0 client, which you
# configured in the API Console. If this value doesn't match an authorized URI,
# you will get a 'redirect_uri_mismatch' error.
flow.redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/oauth2callback'

# Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
# Use kwargs to set optional request parameters.
authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
    # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
    access_type='offline',
    # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
    include_granted_scopes='true')
```

## installed app

If you are using installed / other type credentials then you should have a look at this. You will need to alter it for google drive [Google analytics sample](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py) its the best sample i know of for python with installed applications i dont have the time right now to alter it for you.  If you cant do this on your own let me know in comments and i will give it a go in the morning.

Comment: The console EXPLICITLY PREVENTS YOU FROM ADDING THE TRAILING slash

Comment: I understand your frustration with this error message. However I am not sure where you got that idea from.  I have been doing it for years and I just tried there's nothing stopping you from adding a trailing slash.   Alternatively you could fix your code so it doesn't add the trailing slash but im guessing thats part of the client library directly

Comment: I apologize if I added too much information,  I was trying to be thorough, and may have provided TMI.  I was researching JS just to see if I could get that to work.   I could try and screen print the console, rejecting me with a trailing slash, but mine definitely does.  I suspect that I am not making the correct choices when downloading my json file.  There were several options and I did not understand what the consequences where of choosing one option over another.  I tried a couple and none seemed to work,  until this last one,  what I ended up using was OS Auth2  client and my json

Comment: `          {"installed":
             {"client_id":"_xxx_",
              "project_id":"_xxx_",
              "token_uri":"_xxx_",
              "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"_xxx_",
              "client_secret":"_xxx_",
              "redirect_uris":["_xxx_",
              "http://localhost"]
             }   
          }   `

Comment: I started back at the "top" and went through the process, downloading a new json file, and I get past the 404 error, allow the user access, and then I get to line 15 Authentication successful.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 15, in <module>
    SERVICE = build('drive', 'v3', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))       # from Ref(A):
NameError: name 'credentials' is not defined

Comment: Remember if you are using client credentials for an installed application then your code must also be for an installed application.   If you are using web browser credentials then you must use code designed to work with web browser credentials.

Comment: If you dont know the types of Oauth then you might want to go though this series https://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you DalmTo,  https://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/ is exactly what I need.  A well documented process to follow. The Google documentation was over-whelming, definitely not succinct and in some cases just out-dated.